How to drawing on the TscDBGrid component delphi
When adding the first element to the temporary table, the drawing appears on the TscDBGrid
When adding a second element, the drawing appears normally
But when adding a third element
The drawing is done only on the third element
And the drawing disappears on the first elements
like this code :
procedure THomeForm.scDBGrid1DrawDataCell(Sender: TObject; ACanvas: TCanvas;
  const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: TscGridDrawState);
 var
  StockValue: Integer;
  ProductID: Variant;
begin
  if Dm.FDMemTable1.RecNo > 0 then
  begin
    if Field.FieldName = 'Qte' then
    begin
        ProductID := Dm.FDMemTable1.FieldByName('ProductID').Value;

        if Dm.Qry_Products.Locate('ProductID', ProductID, []) then
        begin
          StockValue := Dm.Qry_Products.FieldByName('Stock').AsInteger;

         with ACanvas do
          begin

            FillRect(Rect);

            if StockValue > 10 then
              Font.Color := clGreen
            else
              Font.Color := clRed;

            TextOut(Rect.Left + 3, Rect.Top + 2, IntToStr(StockValue));
          end;
        end
        else
    end
    else
    begin
     // scDBGrid1.DefaultDrawDataCell(ACanvas,Rect,Field,State);
    end;
  end;



